# Cross-platform method for streaming encrypted video over internet through server

Tags: c++, linux, video, video-streaming, cross-platform

I want to stream encrypted video (with audio) captured from a webcam from one computer to another over the internet with a server in between to forward the video. The program to display the encrypted video will be written in C++ and must be cross-platform; this program will have other functions, so I can't use a currently existing program. The program to stream the video from the webcam must run on Linux. I could use a program already available or write my own in C++.

Comment: I would "use a program [or library] already written" - perhaps there are projects that already provide a [standard] media stream format/playback? I'm sure they exist (as there are *plenty* of existing client programs!), and it's not exactly a "trivial task".

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. StackOverflow is for programming questions, not hardware or general computer advice. The help center has more information about the types of questions that should be asked here. There are other Stack Exchange sites that are more appropriate for this type of question.

Comment: I want to use programs and libraries already written, but I do need to write my own program for displaying the encrypted video since it will also have other functions (controlling the linux-running robot with the webcam).

Answer (score 0):

Try VLC + encypted VPN. It's stable crossplatform solution.